# How to add an object into an array but only when the current element of the array is 0?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, while-loop

I have the code below and when both classes (Player,Game) are instantiated, a specific number of players are inserted in the Player.gameBoard array. I'm trying to add the Player class into the array only if the array element is 0. So if a Player object is inserted into gameboard[0][0] position, no other player can overwrite him. Currently, if a choose a large number of players (e.g.20) some of them are overriden and not all of them appear. So I suppose there is something wrong with the while loop.

```js
var question = prompt('how many players');
var numOfPlayers = parseInt(question);

class Game {
  constructor(){
    this.health = 100;
    this.hammer = false
    this.knife = false;
    this.sword = false;
    this.baseballbat = false;
    this.damage = 0;
    this.gameBoard = [
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ];
    }
  }

class Player {
  constructor(id){
    this.id=id;
    this.location = {
      x:Math.floor(Math.random()*8),
      y:Math.floor(Math.random()*8)
    };
  }
}

var play = new Game();
let player =[];
for (i=0; i <numOfPlayers; i++ ){
    player.push(new Player(i));
    while (play.gameBoard[player[i].location.y][player[i].location.x]===0){
    play.gameBoard[player[i].location.y][player[i].location.x] = player[i];
    }
}

console.log(play);
```

Comment: Your `while` loop only executes if the space is empty, but if it isn't empty, there are no new coordinates generated for the player, and therefore it is skipped/doesn't appear on the grid.

Comment: Players get given a random `x`/`y` - what do you want to happen if that space is taken by another player?

Comment: Rerun Math.floor(Math.random()*8) to get know coordinates

Comment: Then it shouldnt be in the contructor of `Player` and instead done (and assigned to the player) inside the initialization loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of assigning a random `x`/`y` to each player as they are created, you should create a list of all possible locations and pick one at random for each new player instance. You have an 8x8 grid. So there are 64 possible locations

If for each player you:

- pick a random position
- remove that position

You will never have overlaps.

```js
var positions = [];
for(var x=0;x<8;x++){
   for(var y=0;y<8;y++){
      positions.push({x,y});
   }
}

// pick 5 random positions for demo

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
   var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*positions.length);
   console.log("random position chosen:", positions[rnd]);
   //remove this so its not picked again
   positions.splice(rnd,1);
}
```

Applied to your code looks like this:

```js
var question = prompt('how many players');
var numOfPlayers = parseInt(question);

class Game {
  constructor(){
    this.health = 100;
    this.hammer = false
    this.knife = false;
    this.sword = false;
    this.baseballbat = false;
    this.damage = 0;
    this.gameBoard = [
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    ];
    }
  }

class Player {
  constructor(id, location){
    this.id=id;
    this.location = location;
  }
}

var positions = [];
for(var x=0;x<8;x++){
   for(var y=0;y<8;y++){
      positions.push({x,y});
   }
}

var play = new Game();
let player =[];
for (i=0; i <numOfPlayers; i++ ){
    var rndPos = Math.floor(Math.random()*positions.length);    
    player.push(new Player(i, positions[rndPos]));
    positions.splice(rndPos,1);
    play.gameBoard[player[i].location.y][player[i].location.x] = player[i];
}

console.log(play);
```

You could even consider making the `availablePositions` array a property of your `Game` if that makes sense.

Comment: Never thought of this approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure there are new coordinates generated for the player if their position is already filled on the board.

This makes the `for-loop` code look like the following:

```
for (i=0; i <numOfPlayers; i++ ){
   var tempPlayer = new Player(i);
   while (play.gameBoard[tempPlayer.location.y][tempPlayer.location.x]!=0){
      tempPlayer = new Player(i)
    }
   player.push(tempPlayer);
   play.gameBoard[player[i].location.y][player[i].location.x] = player[i];
}
```

At first, you store the new Player locally. Then while the generated coordinates are occupied, you will recreate the Player with the same id. Once the coordinates give an empty space, you will push the player to the `player` array and assign it to the gameboard.

This is an answer based on your current code, but it would be neater to generate the coordinates outside of the `Player()` constructor and assign them to the player when set.